# Background on the bar not getting removed from Highcharts

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I am using highcharts to generate the bar graph. When I hover over the bars a blue background is coming. So, to disable the hover I added the below code snippet,

```
series: {
                states: {
                    hover: {
                        enabled: false
                    }
                }
            }
}
```

But, after that also the blue background is not getting removed on hover. I have added jsfiddle
[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3q6xxhkm/1/)

Comment: The fiddle does not contain the code in your question. Where have you placed it?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan : Can u pls check now

Comment: It looks that your issue is related to using crosshair on your xAxis. You should be able to hide this crosshair by setting xAxis.crosshair to false: http://jsfiddle.net/3q6xxhkm/2/ If my comment will meet your requirements I will post it as an answer

Comment: @GrzegorzBlachliński : Yeah exactly. Worked!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks that your issue is caused by crosshair on xAxis with categories.

It should be possible to disable crosshair feature by setting xAxis.crosshair to false:

```
xAxis: {
crosshair: false,
    categories: [
        'Jan',
        'Feb',
        'Mar',
        'Apr',
        'May',
        'Jun',
        'Jul',
        'Aug',
        'Sep',
        'Oct',
        'Nov',
        'Dec'
    ],
},
```

http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.crosshair

Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/3q6xxhkm/2/